# Remote tile-server as mapnik datasourse

Tags: node.js, mapnik

I need to catch tiles from remote server, repaint them by mapnik and then render them. Is it possible?
Can i use remote tile-server as datasourse for node-mapnik?

Comment: seems it is impossible